# Insecure CORS request sent to ASP.NET Core RC2 API App in Azure fails

Tags: asp.net, azure, cors, .net-core-rc2

I created a new asp.net core rc2 web api application as the official docs at https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/cors.html?highlight=cors.

I was only able to use the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors 1.0.0-rc2-final" package and not the "Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" as per the article.

Then, I am able to configure Cors for any origin. I also created another asp.net core app as a simple client to test CORS. When I deployed both apps on my machine this worked as expected. Without CORS configured my client app is disallowed access but with it enabled it works. However when I publish to Azure I get the classic "Origin 'http://Gonzigonz.azurewebsites.net' is therefore not allowed access."

I also tried removing the Web API CORS configuration I had just added and instead using the Azure App Service CORS feature from the Azure portal but this didn't work either.

I have my code up on Github:
https://github.com/gonzigonz/SampleApp-Backend-ASP.NET-Core-RC2

You can view live versions on Azure:

- Web API: http://gonzigonz-api.azurewebsites.net
- CORS Test Client: http://gonzigonz.azurewebsites.net

It's currently configured using via the Web API nuget package and not the Azure feature.

**UPDATE:** I found that it does work from outside my corporate office. I tested this with my iPad... when connected to the office WiFi it doesn't work but when I switch off WiFi and just use my cellular data it works! I even created a new Azure VM just to double test and it works there!

**UPDATE 2:** It does work from within my corporate office using fiddler... Could the issue be with my client and its AJAX request below?
(jquery-1.11.2)

```
$.ajax({ url: url, cache: false }).always(showResponse);
```

Comment: UPDATE: I found that it does work from outside my corporate office. I tested this with my iPad... when connected to the office WiFi it doesn't work. But then when I switch off WiFi and just use my cellular data it works! I even created a new Azure VM just to double test and it works there!

Comment: UPDATE 2: It does work from within my corporate office using fiddler? Could the issue be with my client and its AJAX request?


$.ajax({ url: url, cache: false }).always(showResponse);

Answer (score 0):

As I see you are setting up CORS this way here:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{
    // Add Cors services.
    services.AddCors();
    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        app.UseCors(builder =>
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
        );
```

What works for me is this (localhost):

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", p => p.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                                                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                                                                     .AllowAnyHeader()));     
        services.AddMvc();            
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors("AllowAll");            
    }
}
```

[GitHub](https://github.com/michalogluszka/shout/blob/master/src/userService/Startup.cs)

[Post](http://michalogluszka.pl/development/cors-with-asp-net-core-rc2/)

Comment: I implemented your approach... its actually clean but it did not work. Did you see my update? It seems to be a caching with our corporate firewall, so I’m investigating that now.

Comment: Ok, so it's something different. I'd assume that when you solve this both of them will work. I'd assume that it's azure thing.

Answer (score 0):

It works if I send my request over HTTPS.

I noticed the issue when I tried my ajax request using [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/MVgbRN) and saw the following console error:

```
VM275 jquery.min.js:4
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://plnkr.co/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://gonzigonz-api.azurewebsites.net/api/todo?_=1463710805503'.
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Sending the request using HTTPS solved the problem, although I still don't know if this is a CORS configuration or Azure restriction that causes it to fail when using the insecure endpoint.